# How to check GPG Keys on AUR files?

Tags: arch-linux, vpn, aur

I don't know how to move the signature (`.asc`) file into my `/opt/Mullvad` folder in order to verify the signature.

I use YAY (AUR Helper). The folder it installs to is read only. How can I move the asc to the `mullvad` folder so I can verify the authenticity through `gpg2 --verify MullvadVPN-*.asc`? As it stands now I am unable to.

See the [package build](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=mullvad-vpn) for details.

Or is it simply enough to read over the `PKGBUILD` for malicious code and be happy with that, since the code does direct to the official GitHub repository?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to move the signature (.asc) file into my /opt/Mullvad folder in order to verify the signature.

`sudo mv MullvadVPN-*.asc /opt/Mullvad`

Alternatively, you can use full paths in the gpg verify command:

`gpg2 --verify /path/to/MullvadVPN-*.asc /opt/Mullvad/signed_file_name`

This way you don't have to move the signature file.

### EDIT

> I use YAY (AUR Helper). The folder it installs to is read only.

If the file was already installed, it's too late to verify the signature.